# Conditionally assigned value not updating immediately

Tags: reactjs

I am working on adding creatable option for mui autocomplete.

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.15.11/docs/data/material/components/autocomplete/FreeSoloCreateOption.js .

The code is as follows

```
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
          value={value}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            if (typeof newValue === "string") {
              setValue({
                title: newValue,
              });
            } else if (newValue && newValue.inputValue) {
              // Create a new value from the user input
              setValue({
                title: newValue.inputValue,
              });
            } else {
              setValue(newValue);
            }
            handleOnChange(event, value); // Issue: value is old one and not the updated one
          }}
        />
    );
```

The issue is that **handleOnChange** is not getting the conditionally assigned value. I know setState is asynchronous. If i use **useEffect** hook,  i need to store **event** also as it is not available outside of onChange code block.

Any idea on getting the updated value inside the onChange block itself?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate) Calling setState does not change the current state in the already executing code.
You can however pass a callback to `setState` (such as your handleOnChange function) as an optional parameter.
From the docs: `React will call the callback you’ve provided after the update is committed`

Comment: Alternatively you can use [componentDidUpdate](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#componentdidupdate) which will be called after your component is re-rendered with new state.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you refactor it to the below

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
          value={value}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            let value = ''
            if (typeof newValue === "string") {
              value = {
                title: newValue,
              }
            } else if (newValue && newValue.inputValue) {
              value = {
                title: newValue.inputValue,
              }
            } else {
              value = newValue
            }
            setValue(value)
            handleOnChange(event, value);
          }}
        />
    );
```

Comment: I am trying to follow the same pattern as it is in https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.15.11/docs/data/material/components/autocomplete/FreeSoloCreateOption.js . It doesn't have the handleOnChange method though.